# Contacts / People application missing

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts

I have no Contacts / People app in my ICS tablet ([bq Maxwell Lite](http://www.bqreaders.com/gb/products/maxwell-lite.html)). All the other google apps are there (calendar, playstore, gmail, talk).

There seem to exist [other tablets with the same problem](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/634595-sum-vison-tablet-no-contact-people-app.html).

I've tried to retrieve the `Contacts` and `ContactsProvider` apks from `/system/app` on the SDK emulator, but these fail to install

Third party contact managers just crash on startup.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some more details: Are other Google Apps there (such as e.g. the playstore app)? What is your device (manufacturer, device name)?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, all other google apps are there (calendar, playstore, gmail, talk). It's a stock rooted [bq Maxwell Lite](http://www.bqreaders.com/gb/products/maxwell-lite.html)

Comment: Thanks, I added the info to your question. Only thing coming to my mind: You could try re-flashing the complete GApps for ICS e.g. from [goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps/).